# Reactive collection query in a template

Tags: meteor

I have a `Template` named `movies`, that has a method that returns a list of objects from a collection.
The query to generate that list of objects is created dynamically using data from another template method.

I would like to re-render the template, or just the components associated with that specific template method, whenever the filter data changes.

Here are the two methods used:

```
  Template.movies.filter = function () {                                             
    if (Session.equals("filter", undefined)) {                                       
      return {};
    }
    return Session.get("filter");                                                    
  };                                                                                 

  Template.movies.movies = function () {                                             
    return Movies.find(Template.movies.filter(), {sort: [["Poster", "desc"]]});
  };
```

On the HTML side it's a simple `{{#each movies}}{{> movie}}{{/each}}` to show the results from the `movies` method.

**The problem** is that when `Session.get("filter")` changes and therefore so does `Template.movies.filter()`, the HTML component relying on `Template.movies.movies()` data won't be updated with the new query results.

How would I achieve that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just make a javascript function that both helpers utilize:

```
var getFilter = function() {
  if (Session.equals("filter", undefined)) {                                       
    return {};
  }
  return Session.get("filter")
}

Template.movies.filter = function() { return getFilter(); }
Template.movies.movies = function () {                                             
  return Movies.find(getFilter(), {sort: [["Poster", "desc"]]});
};
```

This will react as you expect.

Comment: shouldn't getFilter() return either `{}` or `return {movies: Session.get("filter")};` - how does returning just `Session.get("filter")` return anything but what you're searching for and not what your searching...Am I missing something here?

Comment: Perhaps he's putting an object into the session variable.

Comment: Of course...this just opened up all kinds of possibilities.